Is there any smart way to find out the SQL Server link from linked service of adf?
I wanted to find the SQL Servers are present in ADF or not but I am checking the ADF it through a resource group. Is there any smart way to find out the SQL Server link from linked service of ADF?
I tried to do it manually by searching from SQL Server, then RG, then ADF. After that I check ADF's linked services then I totally understand that SQL Servers are present in that particular ADF or not.

can you add what error you are facing and add screenshot of what you tried

Please check the below answer and let me know if there is any issue


Is there any smart way to find out the SQL server link from linked service of adf

You can use CLI to list linked services of type AzureSQLDatabase from ADF and get the server's name from it by using below query.
az datafactory linked-service list --resource-group <Your-Resource-Group> --factory-name <Your-ADF-Name> --query "[?contains(properties.type, 'AzureSqlDatabase')].{LinkedServiceName:name, ServerName:properties.server}" -o json

Output:

